# Live shrink lvm2 partition

Tags: partitioning, lvm

I need to shrink the root partition to give more size to the boot partition. Can I resize/shrink the root lvm2 partition while using it from inside ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Only if it is formatted as Btrfs. Ext4 does not support online shrinking. E.g. I was doing this with KDE Partition Manager 3.0:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FKCQ7pJN1vY

Comment: I mean, what happens if Btrfs is the root mount point (/), could you still be able to shrink it?

Comment: Yeah, look at that youtube video of me doing exactly that. Both (online) shrinking and growing. You can't move partitions online but for LVM logical volumes it doesn't matter. If you boot partition is not inside LVM then you might need to move your LVM PV (depending on where /boot partition is located). By the way, you don't really need  a separate /boot partition...